# Equivalent of pluck to array for $DB->Select("Raw expression here")

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm doing

```
$DB->select(
  "SELECT i::DATE
   FROM generate_series('2019-01-01', '2019-01-05', '1 day'::INTERVAL) i
  ")
```

and it return like

```
[{i : '2019-01-01'},
{i : '2019-01-02'},
{i : '2019-01-03'},
{i : '2019-01-04'},
{i : '2019-01-05'}]
```

which is okay on its own, but how do I get it to form like

```
['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05']
```

?

if it's were like

```
$DB->table("my table")->where("some condition")->get()
```

i can just continue like this

```
->pluck("my desired column (which is i)")->toArray()
```

Comment: `$array = collect($DB->table("my table")->where("some condition")->get())->pluck("i")->toArray();`

Comment: Do `i:DATE as alias` and then `->pluck('alias')` or maybe `->pluck('i')` would also work. The results of raw selects should still be collections

Comment: no I don't have "my table" (see my very first query) it's raw query and collect date from generate_series, not a real table. cannot do Pluck because db->select(raw) is DIFFERENT from db->table()->select()->get(). db->select(raw) cannot be continued with ->get() and pluck

Comment: or should I make temp table from it? so no other solution but make temp table?